# Upgrade from Selenium 2.53 to 3.0.0

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, ruby

Is there an accepted upgrade path from Selenium WebDriver 2.53 to 3.0.0? I'm using the Ruby gem if curious.

Comment: Just download the new Selenium Standalone JAR from seleniumhq.org and replace it with the JAR file you already have in your project.

Comment: There is many other dependency like Java 8 and Firefox latest. Please search more on Official blog of Selenium.

Comment: Nice to see information about the Upgrade from Selenium 2.53 to 3.0.0. Removing older files and installing it will be easier way to perform. I have also started creating the articles related to qa that i have focused to creating test data.
http://softwaretestingterminologies.blogspot.in/2017/03/tips-to-design-your-test-data.html

Answer (score 2):

Selenium 3.0 is a drop-in replacement, so it's as simple as updating your `Gemfile` to use the latest version of Selenium-WebDriver (and any other libraries you want). Then run your package manager to update / install those libraries. For example, when I did this two weeks ago I ran `bundle update` (I use bundler). I deleted the Gemfile.lock prior to updating, just in case.

The only thing consider is that in Selenium 3.0 you'll need to start using GeckoDriver / MarionetteDriver instead of Firefox. That is also a drop-in replacement. If you use MacOS I wrote a post on how to [install it](http://www.kenst.com/2016/12/installing-marionette-firefoxdriver-on-mac-osx/).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, Just update you Jar files from 2.53 to 3.0.0

There are few other dependencies you need to add/update due to the changes in the way selenium was execution before. for example to execute firefox, you need to upgrade to latest version of GeckoDriver and firefox.
You need Java 8.

They have removed APIs related to selenium RC as well, if you are using any of that, you might need to change them accordingly.